# Why does managing a counter and label in an environment make \ref obtain the wrong value?

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, counters

With the following code, I prepare my own custom counter and use it in a command, where I also create a label. Then I use my command several types, and use `\ref` using the label created in each command use.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\refstepcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mynumberedelement}[2]{
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{\arabic{mycounter}}
    \refstepcounter{mycounter}
    #2
}

\begin{document}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel1}{A first element numbered 1}

\emph{Reference to 1} : \ref{mylabel1}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel2}{A second element numbered 2}

\emph{Reference to 2} : \ref{mylabel2}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel3}{A third element numbered 3}

\emph{Reference to 3} : \ref{mylabel3}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel4}{A second element numbered 4}

\emph{Reference to 4} : \ref{mylabel4}


\end{document}
```

The result is what I would expect:

[image]

Next, I add a new environment which does *nothing else* than call my command, and I replace one of my commands with this environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\refstepcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mynumberedelement}[2]{
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{\arabic{mycounter}}
    \refstepcounter{mycounter}
    #2
}

\newenvironment{mynumberedenvironment}[2]{\mynumberedelement{#1}{#2}}{}


\begin{document}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel1}{A first element numbered 1}

\emph{Reference to 1} : \ref{mylabel1}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel2}{A second element numbered 2}

\emph{Reference to 2} : \ref{mylabel2}



\begin{mynumberedenvironment}{mylabel3}{A third element numbered 3, in an environment}
\end{mynumberedenvironment}

\emph{Reference to 3} : \ref{mylabel3}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel4}{A second element numbered 4}

\emph{Reference to 4} : \ref{mylabel4}


\end{document}
```

This time, **the result is not what I expect**:

[image]

As you can see, the last reference does not work.

**How come simply wrapping a command in an environment would mess up such referencing? And what should I do to make this work?**

Comment: how should the label know the value of the counter if the \label command is executed before the \refstepcounter?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain why you get the effect you have, but it is more appropriate to increase the counter *right before you want to use it*, which is also much cleaner.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mynumberedelement}[2]{
    \refstepcounter{mycounter} % <------
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{\arabic{mycounter}}
    #2
}

\newenvironment{mynumberedenvironment}[2]{\mynumberedelement{#1}{#2}}{}


\begin{document}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel1}{A first element numbered 1}

\emph{Reference to 1} : \ref{mylabel1}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel2}{A second element numbered 2}

\emph{Reference to 2} : \ref{mylabel2}



\begin{mynumberedenvironment}{mylabel3}{A third element numbered 3, in an environment}
\end{mynumberedenvironment}

\emph{Reference to 3} : \ref{mylabel3}



\mynumberedelement{mylabel4}{A second element numbered 4}

\emph{Reference to 4} : \ref{mylabel4}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As an added bonus, you get the correct spacing between your counter and your text.
In your original post, they were separated by two spaces (one after the line `\textbf{\arabic{mycounter}}`, one after the line `\refstepcounter{mycounter}`.
Now, only one space remains.

---

**Update:** Maybe this helps.
This is taken from the [unofficial reference manual for LaTeX2e](https://latexref.xyz/dev/latex2e.pdf), §13.6, on `\refstepcounter`:

> In addition, this command also defines the current \ref value to be the result of
> \thecounter.
>
> While the counter value is set globally, the \ref value is set locally, i.e., inside the current
> group.

So there are some issues between global and local settings.

Answer (score 1):

The `\label` command always refers to the last number that has been generated with `\refstepcounter`. So, if you have something like

```
\section{Foo}

Some text

\label{x}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}
```

the label will refer to the section number. And this is what happens with your code: the `\label` is always *ahead* of the relevant `\refstepcounter`.

Fix follows. Also look at `%` and `\par` in the definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mynumberedelement}[2]{%
    \par
    \refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{#1}%
    \textbf{\arabic{mycounter}} #2\par
}

\begin{document}

\mynumberedelement{mylabel1}{A first element numbered 1}

\emph{Reference to 1}: \ref{mylabel1}


\mynumberedelement{mylabel2}{A second element numbered 2}

\emph{Reference to 2}: \ref{mylabel2}


\mynumberedelement{mylabel3}{A third element numbered 3}

\emph{Reference to 3}: \ref{mylabel3}


\mynumberedelement{mylabel4}{A second element numbered 4}

\emph{Reference to 4}: \ref{mylabel4}

\end{document}
```

[image]